# RShiny integration with google sites

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to be able to add interactive shiny elements into a website. My HTML skills are not up to speed to make fancy websites from scratch. Google allows you to make nice slick well functioning websites fast, using sites.google.com.

I was wondering if it is possible to add R Shiny elements into a sites.google.com site.

For example, it is possible to put

```
library(plotly) 
trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5) 
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0) 
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5) 
x <- c(1:100) 
data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2) 
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%  
add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines+markers') %>% 
add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'markers')
```

into https://sites.google.com/view/shinytest ?

**EDIT:** I read that in Shiny you can build a 'raw' HTML UI instead of a ShinyUI (shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html). Would it be possible to extract the HTML from an existing site (e.g. the sites.google site from the example and keep all its functionality) and start using that as a base HTML UI in which Shiny elements can be added (and thususing the server part as back-end)?

Comment: Google sites offer static pre-rendered content. Shiny requires a server. You can deploy it either to AWS, Shinyapps.io, google server or any other platform where you have a shiny-server and them iframe that into the site. You can use markdown however to generate content

Comment: So, I read that in Shiny you can build a 'raw' HTML UI instead of a ShinyUI (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html). Would it be possible to extract the HTML from an existing site (e.g. the sites.google site from the example and keep all its functionality) and start using that as a HTML UI?

Comment: You can yes, but you need a server, as you can see on that link its running off localhost (e.g. 127.0.0.1:4397). as shiny running on top of `nodejs` its not static like `markdown` for example. I think you should revisit tutorials on shiny https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/